# Antiprime Champions

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Consider the following table for the function `d(n)`, which calculates the number of factors that `n` is divisible by without a remainder:

```
n    | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | ...
d(n) | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 4  | 2  | 6  | ...
```

Going from left to right, it is possible to determine the "champion" of the current subsequence:

- The first champion in the sequence `[1]` is `n = 1` with `d(1) = 1`.
- The second champion in the next sequence, `[1, 2]` is `n = 2` with `d(2) = 2`.
- The sequence `[1, 2, 3]` has no new champions, because `d(3) = d(2) = 2`, and `2` earned the title first.
- The third champion appears the sequence `[1, 2, 3, 4]`: `d(4) = 3`, which is greater than the previous champion with `d(2) = 2`.
- The next champion is `6` in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` with `d(6) = 4`.
- The next champion is `12` with `d(12) = 6`.

The champions can be denoted in the table:

```
n    | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | ...
d(n) | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 4  | 2  | 6  | ...
       x   x       x       x                         x
```

You task is the following: Write a program that given an integer `n`, print all champions in the range `[1, n]` (`n` inclusive). The output format does not matter (test cases below display array format). Standard code golf rules and scoring applies.

### Test cases

```
1 -> [1]
2 -> [1, 2]
3 -> [1, 2]
4 -> [1, 2, 4]
5 -> [1, 2, 4]
6 -> [1, 2, 4, 6]
7 -> [1, 2, 4, 6]
8 -> [1, 2, 4, 6]
9 -> [1, 2, 4, 6]
10 -> [1, 2, 4, 6]
11 -> [1, 2, 4, 6]
12 -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 12]
24 -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 12, 24]
36 -> [1, 2, 4, 6, 12, 24, 36]
```

Hint: The output should always be a prefix of the [List of Highly Composite Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number).

Comment: [Obligatory OEIS](https://oeis.org/A002182)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! This is a good challenge, except uoi don't define what a "champion" is.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere - The OP does implicitly. "d(3) = d(2) = 2, and 2 earned the title first." and "d(4) = 3, which is greater than the previous champion with d(2) = 2", so a champion must be **the next greater d(n) for greater n**. (If `d(n) > d(n-x)` where `x > 0`, it is a champion)

Comment: @owacoder: Sorry, I didn't see that.

Comment: This is inspired by the [new Numberphile video](http://youtu.be/2JM2oImb9Qg), isn't it?

Comment: I am telling you the name is going to stick!

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Yes, nice spot!

Comment: Well somebody watched a numberphile video recently ;)

Answer (score 3):

## Jelly, 10 bytes

```
0rÆDL€»\IT
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MHLDhkRM4oKswrtcSVQ&input=&args=MzY)

Answer (score 2):

### 05AB1E, <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
0U>GNÑg©X›i®UN,
```

**Explanation**

```
0U               # initialize the record as 0
  >G             # for each number in 1 to N
    NÑg©         # get number of divisors
        X›i      # if number of divisors is a new record
           ®U    # save new record
             N,  # print the new record holder on a new line
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MFU-R07DkWfCqVjigLppwq5VTiw&input=MzY)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
0i:t!\~sY>hdf
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MGk6dCFcfnNZPmhkZg&input=MzY)

#### Explanation

```
0      % Push 0
i:     % Take input n. Push [1 2 ... n]
t!\    % 2D array of all combinations of modulo between elements of [1 2 ... n]
~s     % Sum of zeros of each column. Gives number of divisors for [1 2 ... n]
Y>     % Cumulative maximum
h      % Concatenate with 0 
d      % Consecutive differences
f      % Indices of nonzero elements. Implicitly display
```

Comment: Woah! I did not know you could create a 2d matrix like that! That's really cool! Also, you could take 2 bytes off by just pushing a one, instead of joining it, since output format doesn't matter. http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OnQhXH5zWT5kZlEx&input=MzY

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan Yes, I use [broadcasting](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Broadcasting.html) all the time :-) As for the format, I assume the numbers have to be at least sorted

Comment: Well, OP said `The output format does not matter (test cases below display array format).` but I suppose it's up to you.